# After i update global variable in a function, why i cannot access that updated version in another function? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, global-variables

HTML

```
<select class="button-style_dropdown" id="levelOption" onchange="OnSelectionChange (this)">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Difficulty</option>
  <option class="level_options" id="bronze_option" value="bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option class="level_options" id="silver_option" value="silver">Silver</option>
  <option class="level_options" id="gold_option" value="gold">Gold</option>
</select>
```

Here is global variable.

```
var myglobal = "";
```

And the function that gets called as soon as i change option in selection menu

```
function OnSelectionChange(select) {
  var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

  if (selectedOption.value === "silver") {    
    myglobal = selectedOption.value;    
  }
}
```

This is where i call ajax function

```
$(".window-popup").fadeIn(function() {
  ajaxScore();
});
```

Here is my Ajax function

```
function ajaxScore() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions.php?action=yourScore",
    data: "score=" + $("#final-score").html() + "&option=" + myglobal,
    success: function(result) {
      if ($.trim(result) != '1') {
        $("#noLoginalert").html(result).show();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

OnSelectionChange function gets call before the ajax, I would expect my global variable to be updated in that function and when i use it in the ajax function I was expecting it to be the updated version but I still get ("") this value which i assigned in the global scope. I cant seem to resolve this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling your ajax function?

Comment: As an aside from the problem itself, I'd say your pattern of using a global variable is flawed from the start. It would be much better to actually read the value from the `select` at the point you make the AJAX request.

Comment: 1st of all you have to check  "  if(selectedOption.value === "silver"){} " is true or not .After that you can verify myglobal variable is set or not

Comment: after adding this to my ajax function (async: false) it worked:) thanks guys anyway